# How do you show an alert box after clicking a button on Procedure Editor

Tags: openedge

Trying to get a message to show after clicking a button on Procedure Editor. I'm not sure what the button clicking command is the display the alert box.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FnDF.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLNTz.png

Comment: Please show at least a little bit of sample code that illustrates where you are having a problem.

Comment: Well, that's the thing. I'm not sure what code I need in order to create an alert box when the button is clicked on

Comment: Surely you can show some code that creates a button that you would like to associate this alert box with?

Comment: I have included some screenshots of the button that I need the code for (b-enquiry)

Answer (score 1):

The button click is captured with the `ON CHOOSE OF` event. In that code block you can put the required business logic. To show a message, use the `MESSAGE` statement.

```
ON CHOOSE OF b-ok:
DO:
    MESSAGE "Button OK clicked." VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION.
END.
```

Answer (score 0):

Needless to say, create your button myButtonName prior to this, do everything in order to make it enabled in your program, and the core of what you want to do would look something like this:
ON 'CHOOSE' OF myButtonName DO:
MESSAGE 'HELLO WORLD' VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX
INFORMATION.
End.

Comment: Thanks very much for the straightforward answer, this helped me greatly.